# Как получить Bitmap из Gif?

Tags: java, android

Простым открытием файла не получается. Примерный код:

```
File f = new File(path);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap out = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, options);
```

Изображения открывает, а при попытке открыть gif (анимированный и нет, большой и маленький, любой):

> Attempt to read from field 'int android.graphics.Bitmap$Config.nativeInt' on a null object

Как получить bitmap из этого формата?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042993/convert-gif-to-png-programatically посмотрите здесь

Comment: Это не работает.

Comment: Тогда, можно попробовать разобрать гифку на фреймы, и взять например первую картинку.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19172326/9008111

Comment: Всем спасибо, я нашел оптимальный вариант: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736861/10158547

Answer (score 0):

Используйте лучше библиотеки. Что бы не было, за вас это уже наверняка сделали. 
Вот одна из библиотек, что бы заценили: https://github.com/rtyley/animated-gif-lib-for-java

https://gist.github.com/devunwired/4479231
Хотя GIF это несколько картинок с определенным delay

Comment: Библиотеки это хорошо, но не хочется в приложение ~35 кб пихать их. Я искал простую реализацию получения bitmap из gif, и только лишь это. Мне не нужна анимация, работа с анимированными изображениями и прочее, только лишь bitmap. В нативе простых решений нет, как я понял. Пойду изучать реализацию в библиотеках. Спасибо за ответ ☺